# Select an Image in a contenteditable DIV

Tags: javascript

With Javascript, I want to select an Image Object in a contenteditable DIV. After the selection (in Internet Explorer) the selected Image should have corners which can be dragged via Mouse. I mean the same corners which usually appear, when I manually click the Image.

This is the image which should be selected (corners should appear):

```
<div id="editor" contenteditable="true">
<img src="//www.google.com/images/logos/google_logo_41.png" id="google_logo">
</div>
```

I already did a unsuccessful try in http://jsfiddle.net/4Ynvv/7/

Does someone have a (Crossbrowser) solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about a crossbrowser solution, but know how to get it working in IE.

Check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/VJD5Q/

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very very much! Now I hope, someone has also a solution also for FF, Safari, Chrome and Opera :-)

Comment: @Max Bad thing is that WebKit-based browsers do not support resize handles: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8040909/webkit-live-images-resize-in-contenteditable-container

Comment: Does someone also have a solution for FF, Safari, Chrome and Opera?

Comment: @Max If I find some spare time tonight or tomorrow, I'll do it.

Comment: Hmm, still waiting for a crossbrowser solution... :-)

Comment: @Igor, how would we make it maintain the aspect ratio when resizing?