# Resizable/Draggable Image using jQuery in ContentEditable

Tags: jquery, contenteditable

I am tweaking a WYSIWYG editor for a CMS.

I would like to allow the user to upload pictures and then resize them in the UI using handles and drag the image around within the editor.  I'm having trouble getting this to work properly - this is what I have done so far:

```
$("img").resizable(
{
    autoHide: true,
    containment: "parent",
    aspectRatio: true,
    handles:"ne,nw,se,sw",
    minHeight: 100,
    minWidth: 100,
})
```

Here is an example:
https://jsfiddle.net/wyeack/6y92p28L/10/

I feel like this should be much easier - what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can use this question and the answers/comments as reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8040909/webkit-live-images-resize-in-contenteditable-container

Comment: @Dekel - that appears to be referring to the native resizing of Firefox vs. Chrome, etc.  I am using jQuery UI - which should work consistently across browsers -

Comment: I know, this is why I also mentioned the comments :) read more

Comment: @Dekel - I see what you meant now - http://editorboost.net/Webkitresize/Demos is definitely a possibility, but it does not seem to be very actively maintained (it has been three years since the last update).  It seems like there would be more solutions than just this as well - I would think that alot of people have had to solve this problem.  Do you know of any other alternative methods?

Comment: No, sorry. I did a quick search and thought my findings might help :)